# OOP PDO fetch while loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a function in my class which is not completed. I'm searching a way to do it all night long. Well I want to fetch all the result of a SELECT request to MYSQL using PDO in a OOP class/function.

Here my function

```
function select($query)
{
    try
    {
    $sql = $this->connect->query($query);
        while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
        return ????
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {  
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }

}
```

I know that I can do it with a while loop, I tested a few options but most of the time I only got 1 result. Anyone a point for me, where I could start my search for a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy, actually.  You use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` and specify which class you want to instantiate for each row.

Here is an example that fetches all available rows as an array of objects of class `YourClassName`.

```
function select($query) {
    try {
        $sql = $this->connect->query($query);
        return $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, YourClassName);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {  
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use `$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` within the while loop, not before, as you have it.

So, like:

```
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // something
}
```

Comment: yeah, remarked that as I posted the code ... the // something is what am missing... any points how I could go for it ?

Comment: items from `$row` are fetched like they are in an array. If you are doing `select name from pets` you would access it like: `$row['name']`